# Android FCM push notification not launching the application on click

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im sending a notification via the FCM legacy api like so:

```
// POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
{
    "to": "<device-token>",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Test!",
        "body": "testing",
        "mutable_content": true,
        "sound": "Tri-tone",
        "click_action": "https://example.com/1234"
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="cx.myapp.android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application 
    android:name=".MainApplication" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
    android:allowBackup="false" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/light" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
</manifest>
```

The notification is being received, but it does not launch the application when it's clicked.

Interestingly, if I launch the application myself, the notification is received in the react-native linking event callbacks.

So its like everything is working except the app launching! Frustrating.

Note; deep links worked with the same url in "click_action" testing with `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com/some-deep-link" cx.myapp.android`.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have tried adding the below to my manifest underneath my .MainActivity. Then I have tried sending the notification with "click_action": "TESTING" with no luck.

```
<activity
      android:name="TESTING"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="TESTING" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be the intent-filter created for the Activity, here's how it should look:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.your_activity_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.your activity page"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>                
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As you can see the value of the key ***click_action*** should be the same as the one in `<action android:name="the same value">` of the intent filter.
Also, it might be because of the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />`, you might try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't seem to help. It's interesting as the notification is associated with the app as the badge is showing. When I click the notification, the badge is cleared, just the app doesn't launch/foreground.

Comment: It seems to be because the intent for app opening is not correct, so the activity doesn't start.